# jQuery hiding other divs when another radio button is selected

Tags: jquery, radio-button, hide, toggle, show

I need help with toggling my radio buttons. Whenever I click one of them it opens up like its suppose to, but when I choose a different one, it doesn't close. I only want one open at a time. Any help is much appreciated - thanks!

Here's the code:

```
jQuery('.selectDiv3').click(function() {jQuery('#div3')[ (jQuery(this).val() == 'NW WI') ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']()});

jQuery('.selectDiv4').click(function() {jQuery('#div4')[ (jQuery(this).val() == 'SE MN') ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']()});

jQuery('.selectDiv5').click(function() {jQuery('#div5')[ (jQuery(this).val() == 'SW MN') ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']()});

jQuery('.selectDiv6').click(function() {jQuery('#div6')[ (jQuery(this).val() == 'SE WI') ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp']()});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your click handlers need the ability to close all other divs. So something like this:

```
jQuery('.selectDiv3').click(function() {
    jQuery('.commonDivClass').slideUp(); // <-- this line
    jQuery('#div3')[ (jQuery(this).val() == 'NW WI')
        ? 'slideDown'
        : 'slideUp']();
});
```

So you add a class to all your divs (e.g. #3-6) and indiscriminately slide them up before sliding down the correct one.